# How to delete all other characters except match case using Regex

Tags: regex, linux, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMFullAccess
arn:aws:iam::s:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSSupportServiceRolePolicy
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSTrustedAdvisorServiceRolePolicy
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AmazonElasticFileSystemServiceRolePolicy
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMAccessAnalyzerFullAccess
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSBackupServiceLinkedRolePolicyForBackup
```

Here i need only the policy names which is at the end.

I need only the letters after /

this is the regex am using `(?<=/).*`

the output of this regex is this

1. arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/`AdministratorAccess`
2. arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/`aws-service-role/AWSSupportServiceRolePolicy`

As you can see in 1) it is greping correctly, but in 2) i need the letters after the last occurrence of /

and i need to delete everything except the match case.

Kindly someone drop your suggestions to achieve this.

Note: am aware that i can get the aws policy names using boto3, but am curious about the above usecase.

Comment: Try it like this `(?<=/)[^/\r\n]+$` https://regex101.com/r/ISUGf3/1 or with `grep -oP` like `.*\/\K[^/\r\n]+$` https://regex101.com/r/JpuJXY/1

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `grep` with regexp and write result in another file. the remove original, if you want.
Something like

```
grep -Eao '\(?<=/).*' 'logs.log' >result.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookbehind assertion, and then match any char except a `/` or newline till the end of the string `[^/\r\n]+$`

```
(?<=/)[^/\r\n]+$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ISUGf3/1)

If you use PCRE, you can also make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

```
.*\/\K[^/\r\n]+$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpuJXY/1).